# Is there a way to have a "from and to" field , need this for business hours "to and from"

Tags: forms, fields, dates

I want to record the working hours from my prospects, so I need a flexible to and from field, like:

9-5, 8-5 etc...

I could do drop down selects, but I would rather have it custom, so a double drop down selection field, a little like the date field but only for hours , no date, month etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently available in CiviCRM to have time range custom field. The alternate solution would be to create two date time field To and From and using buildForm hook and PageRun hook and/or JS hide the date field on forms and view.

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 2):

A more basic solution would be two integer, number or text 'select' fields ie with 8.00, 8.30, 9.00 etc

but it depends whether the data is based on hour, half hour, or by the minute

Comment: Hour is fine, but i need the fields inline select  side by side horizintally,  so could use float left  css for it

Comment: or if drupal do as webform and use layout component